# Vector error: no matching member function call to insert

Tags: c++

I am attempting to insert into a vector that I initialized as

```
std::vector<std::string> vector_strings{""};
```

and I am trying to test inserting by doing

```
vector_strings.insert(vector_strings.begin(),c);
```

in this case, c is a const char.

It keeps giving me this error:

```
no matching member function for call to 'insert'
 note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char' to 'const
      std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >::value_type'
      (aka 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>') for 2nd argument
    iterator insert(const_iterator __position, const_reference __x);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You have a vector of *strings* and try to inserts a *single character* into the vector? Does that sound like it would make sense?

Comment: Please, in any case, you need to extract and provide a [mcve]. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

change from
`vector_strings.insert(vector_strings.begin(),c);`

to
`vector_strings.insert(vector_strings.begin(),string(1,c));`

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

Your `std::vector` has a inner value type of `std::string`.

The thing you're trying to insert is a `const char` which is not a `std::string`.

`const char` is not automatically or implicitly converted into `std::string`. Therefore, the compiler rejects this code.

Convert your `const char` into a `std::string` and it will work.